# Flask-SQLAlchemy invalid identifier on ID column

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use the Python Terminal to add a user using the following commands:

```
from app import db
from app.models import User, Post
u = User(username='Jordan',email='jtest@test.net')
db.session.add(u)
db.session.commit()
```

Below is my model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author',lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'User {}'.format(self.username)
```

Init script:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config, SnowflakeImpl
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

# Creates an instance of the flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError) (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7
invalid identifier 'ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO user (id, username, email, password) VALUES (%(id)s, %(username)s, %(email)s, %(password_hash)s)'] [parameters: [{'email': 'jtest@test.net', 'username': 'Jordan', 'password': None}]] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

This is the error I am receiving, from what I've read online this should work but it's feeding back an 'invalid identifier' error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, since I am using the flask migrate package I went into the versions folder and observed in the migrate script for my User table my 'Sequence' function was not being included. It was causing my ID to have an Invalid Identifier error.

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_table('user',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('username', sa.String(length=64), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(length=120), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('password_hash', sa.String(length=128), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('email'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('username')
)
```

Comment: Could you tell us how you fixed this? Did you add the sequence object manually to the migration?

Comment: Added it into the model script and did an upgrade